# Getting circular reference with autofixture even after omit the behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, autofixture, xunit2

I have the below test method, and I am using `AutoFixture.Xunit2` for testing purposes.

```
[UsesVerify]
public class UpdateWorkspaceTests : TestBase
{
    private readonly Fixture _fixture;
    public UpdateWorkspaceTests()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();
        _fixture.Behaviors.OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>().ToList().ForEach(b => _fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));
        _fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior(1));
    }

    [Theory, AutoData]
    public async Task UpdateWorkspace_ValidUpdate_OnUpdatedEvent(Workspace workspace)
    {     
        _dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<Workspace>()).ReturnsDbSet(new List<Workspace> { workspace });
        _dbContextFactoryMock.Setup(f => f.CreateDbContextAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                            .ReturnsAsync(_dbContextMock.Object);

        var request = new UpdateWorkspaceInput(
            workspace.Id,
            "Workspace2 - New Name",
            "Workspace2 - Description"
            );

        var handler = new UpdateWorkspaceHandler(_dbContextFactoryMock.Object, _eventSenderMock.Object);
        Workspace? updatedWorkspace = await handler.Handle(request, _cancellationToken);

        _eventSenderMock.Verify(
              mock => mock.SendAsync(
                  nameof(WorkspaceSubscriptions.OnUpdatedWorkspace),
                  updatedWorkspace,
                  _cancellationToken),
              Times.Once);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have configured that `OmitOnRecursionBehavior` but still getting the same exception, and exception details are below,

```
    Message: 
AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath : AutoFixture was unable to create an instance of type AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest because the traversed object graph contains a circular reference. Information about the circular path follows below. This is the correct behavior when a Fixture is equipped with a ThrowingRecursionBehavior, the default. This ensures that you are being made aware of circular references in your code. Your first reaction should be to redesign your API to get rid of all circular references. However, if this is not possible (most likely because parts or all of the API is delivered by a third party), you can replace this default behavior with a different behavior: on the Fixture instance, remove the ThrowingRecursionBehavior from Fixture.Behaviors, and instead add an instance of OmitOnRecursionBehavior:

fixture.Behaviors.OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>().ToList()
    .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));
fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());

                

Request path:
    SchemaModeler.Domain.Organization DefaultOrganization
      SchemaModeler.Domain.User
        SchemaModeler.Domain.User User
          SchemaModeler.Domain.OrganizationUser
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SchemaModeler.Domain.OrganizationUser]
              System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SchemaModeler.Domain.OrganizationUser] collection
                System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SchemaModeler.Domain.OrganizationUser]
                  System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[SchemaModeler.Domain.OrganizationUser]
                    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[SchemaModeler.Domain.OrganizationUser] Users
                      SchemaModeler.Domain.Organization
                        SchemaModeler.Domain.Organization Organization
                          SchemaModeler.Domain.Workspace
                            SchemaModeler.Domain.Workspace workspace


  Stack Trace: 
ThrowingRecursionHandler.HandleRecursiveRequest(Object request, IEnumerable`1 recordedRequests)
RecursionGuard.HandleRecursiveRequest(Object request)
ObsoletedMemberShims.RecursionGuard_HandleRecursiveRequest(RecursionGuard guard, Object request)
RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
Fixture.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
SpecimenContext.Resolve(Object request)
SeedIgnoringRelay.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
<208 more frames...>
Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
AutoPropertiesTarget.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
BehaviorRoot.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
Fixture.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
SpecimenContext.Resolve(Object request)
AutoDataAttribute.Resolve(ParameterInfo p)
AutoDataAttribute.GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)

  (result has additional output)
```

I don't know how to fix this. Could anyone please help avoid this circular reference issue with any other solution? That would be very grateful to me.

Many thanks in advance!!